# EditForm.aspx with attachment -> edit Attachment online, click "Save" --> "Save Conflict error"

Tags: jsom, save

If You have item with attachment, then open attachment in new tab and edit it - Your Edit form will not be saved.

> Save Conflict. Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by
>   another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in
>   your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.

I created my own button that uploads attachments and then refreshes page, but You can reproduce this behaviour in **out-out-the-box lists** too

Here guys changed "Unprotected" setting but I don't see it.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd1a1437-769c-4fc3-9346-4cdcbbb3289c/save-conflict-when-editing-or-uploading-attachments-to-list-item?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Also I have idea to turn On "Unsafe Updates", not sure I can do it in SpOnline2013..

Any ideas how to avoid it?

**upd.:** can I reload attachments on PreSave or something similar?.. I use JSOM, REST

**upd2.:** tried to update item in PreSaveAction, but get same error (tha't Ok, I really made a save conflict). But how to allow to **change attachments** from Edit form..

```
function PreSaveAction() {
// Get current iten and list ID
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["ID"];
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;

// Update current item
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
item.update();

context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
console.log("Item updated successfully");
}, function() {
console.log("Error updating item");
});

// delay here
// ..
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open attachment in current tab by removing target="_blank" attribute to your links(anchor tags)

Open attachment in Microsoft Web App by appending ?Web=1 at the end of attachment Url.

```
var newAttachmentUrl = oldAttachmentUrl + "?Web=1";
```

Comment: Hi Jain! If I open attachment on current window I loose all changes from form. I think no matter how You open attachment - if file changes there will be "Save Conflict".

Comment: Have tried open in web app

Comment: Yes I tried to copy-paste attachment url and add Your key, same result

Comment: https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/sharepoint-error-save-conflict-your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user/

Comment: Thank You Jain, I've googled these pages. My problem is with out-of-the-box lists and out-of-the-box attachments